# How to add entity field to joined documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have an e-commerce server where I have a `products` and an  `orders` collection.

Any `product` document contains a unique `productId` e.g. `prod_123`.
Each `order` document contains a `lineItems` (array) field which returns the `productId`s of the purchased products as well as the respective `quantity` purchased e.g.

```
[{ productId: 'prod_123', quantity: 2 }, { productId: 'prod_234', quantity: 7 }, ...]
```

When my client fetches their orders, I want to populate the each of the `lineItems` elements' `productId` with the matching product document in the `products` collection.

I have written a mongoDB aggregation pipeline to achieve this, and this is it so far:

```
 const orderPipeline = [
    {
      $match: { customerId: 'the customer's ID' },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'products',
        let: { productIds: '$lineItems.productId' },
        pipeline: [
          { $match: { $expr: { $in: ['$productId', '$$productIds'] } } },
          //*** somehow, need to add in corresponding `lineItem.quantity` here
        ],
        as: 'products',
      },
    },
    { $unset: ['lineItems'] },
  ];
```

However, as you can see, though the join is taking place, I cannot work out how to add the matched product's `quantity` to the joined `product` before I remove `lineItems`.

How can I add the corresponding `quantity` to the corresponding matched `product`?

Comment: Are documents in `products` unique based on `productId`? Will there ever be a product in the `lineItems` that doesn't have a corresponding entry in `products`? Said another way, is this going to be a `1:1` match between entries in the array and documents in the other collection?

Comment: Yes, documents in `products` are unique based on their `productId`. And no, every `lineItem` will always have a matching `product`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach, that I'm *pretty sure* will work given the additional constraints mentioned in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74382671/how-to-add-entity-field-to-joined-documents?noredirect=1#comment131317447_74382671), would be to leverage [the `$zip` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/). Overall it would work like this:

1. Perform the `$lookup` generating an array (`products`) with the information retrieved from the other collection.
2. Use an `$addFields` stage as the place where most of the combination logic happens. It will `$zip` the two arrays together and then `$map` over it to `$mergeObjects` each of the pairs into a single object.
3. Finish with an `$unset` stage to remove the original `lineItems` field (which has already been merged into the recreated `products` array.

The full pipeline would look something like this:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      customerId: 123
    },
    
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "products",
      let: {
        productIds: "$lineItems.productId"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$productId",
                "$$productIds"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "products",
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "products": {
        "$map": {
          "input": {
            "$zip": {
              "inputs": [
                "$lineItems",
                "$products"
              ]
            }
          },
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": "$$this"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "lineItems"
  }
])
```

[Playground example here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UeXGclkVJuA)

The `$map` and the `$mergeObjects: "$$this"` probably look odd at first glance. This is needed because the `$zip` is going to generate an array of arrays (with 2 entries each), such as this:

```
    "zipped": [
      [
        {
          "productId": "a",
          "quantity": 1
        },
        {
          "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
          "productId": "a"
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "productId": "b",
          "quantity": 2
        },
        {
          "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
          "productId": "b"
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "productId": "c",
          "quantity": 3
        },
        {
          "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000004"),
          "productId": "c"
        }
      ]
    ]
```

([Here is a playground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7nSpXdqt4qu) that shows the output after zipping but before further processing.)

Because of this we need to collapse each of those into a single object, hence the `$mergeObjects`. And the fact that each object in the outer array is an array (with the two objects we want to merge) is why we can simply use `"$$this"` as the input expression for the operator.

Comment: Really is a fantastic answer. Thank you for taking the time to explain each step, because I've learnt new aggregation applications as a result! Have a wonderful day!